# Intel video driver breaks HDMI output after boot

Tags: display, hdmi, intel-graphics

I have Asus 27T1E display (for the record it's more of TV by nature that is being marketed as computer display, line is blurry there) that is used with my current PC (Mini-ITX build with some integrated nvidia GPU) over HDMI.

I am putting together new PC with:

- Core i7 CPU (integrated HD 3000 GPU)
- Z68 motherboard (HDMI, DVI and VGA outputs)
- Windows 7 Home Premium x64
- no discrete video card

As soon as **Intel video drivers are installed - after "Starting Windows" logo display falls into "No Signal" mode**. As far as I can tell Windows continues to work fine (I can blindly Alt+F4 and shutdown).

- it doesn't matter how driver is installed, tried:

  - Windows update
  - download from Intel (appropriate x64 version)
- generic Windows VGA driver works fine
- safe mode works fine (with any driver)
- VGA cable works fine (with any driver)

There should be no faulty hardware involved (as far as I see):

- display works fine over same HDMI cable with old computer
- new computer works fine without Intel driver installed

So the only precise combination that fails is **Intel driver + HDMI + normal boot**.

Comment: Have you set the HDMI port to be the primary video display, via the BIOS? (IGD Primary Video Port)

Comment: @techie007 I do not have such setting (or it is called something else, or I can't locate it - Asus BIOS in "advanced" mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue went away after uninstalling/re-installing Intel driver, while using VGA cable, and switching to HDMI cable after that.

However I am not sure if these actions had really helped or just something had clicked inside on umpteenth attempt.

PS of course now I get crazy overscan... I hate HDMI.

Comment: Solved it for me too, except instead of using VGA cable I was using RDP to see what I was doing